# reveal negation in the Text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, nltk

I have a program that analyzes user comments (reviews) in the data frame. The idea is that everything that meets the word cheap increases the variable x.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk

def get_review_words(review):
    review_words = nltk.word_tokenize(review)
    for i in range (0, len(review_words)):
        review_words[i] = review_words[i].lower()
    return review_words

df = pd.read_csv("lastFile3.csv", sep=',' )


wordList= ['cheap']
x = 0
review_words =  get_review_words(str(df['review_text'].loc[i]))
if any(item in wordList for item in review_words):
    x += 1
```

My question is, how can I take into account cases of negation, so that, for example, if the text not cheap is mentioned, it is not taken into account.
Likewise for all cases  (not cheap,never,not be, ...)
Can someone help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some sample sentences, please?

Answer (score 0):

A very basic, rule-based approach would be:

- Define a list of negation indication words (`never, not, no, don't/dont/doesn't/doesnt, can't/..., won't/..., ...`), you can probably find ressources for this online
- Iterate through the tokens in a review, when a negation word is used, assume any usage of "cheap" means the opposite in the scope of that negation word
- The scope of the negation can be assumed e.g. as being limited by the next punctuation character (`.`, `,`, `!`, `?`, ...), check out for example https://analyticsindiamag.com/when-to-use-negation-handling-in-sentiment-analysis/
- Think about what to do when you found such probably negated words (e.g. exclude these cases from the analysis, use them in the opposite direction analysis, ...)

Note that this is a probability-based approach and can fail in a lot of cases, so you will have to try out if applying this actually improves your results or the analysis works better without it.